# Retrieving Data from an Array (cannot seem to get it working)

Tags: mips

I'm currently working on a palindrome function in MIPS that takes a char array and returns 0 if it is not a palindrome, else 1. I've got everything seemingly working except for the part where I find data at index i and array.length-i-1. If someone could lead me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it.

Here's the java code I'm going off of:

```
int Palindrome(char[] s) {
    for(int i = 0; i < (s.length / 2); i++) {
        if(s[i] != s[s.length - 1 - i])
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Here's the Palindrome function:

```
palindrome:
# Get length of array and store it in $t1
addi $sp, $sp, -8
sw $ra, 0($sp)
sw $a0, 4($sp)
li $t1, 0

lengthWhile:
lw $t2, 0($a0)
beq $t2, $zero, startPalindrome
addi $t1, $t1, 1
addi $a0, $a0, 4
j lengthWhile

startPalindrome:
div $t2, $t1, 2       # Stores a.length / 2 into $t2
add $t3, $t3, $zero   # i value (0 - (a.length/2 - 1))
add $t4, $t4, $t1
subi $t4, $t4, 1      # a.length-1

# $t1 = a.length
# $t2 = a.length / 2
# $t3 = i
# $t4 = a.length - 1

palLoop:
bge $t3, $t2, exitLoop
sub $t4, $t4, $t3 # Puts a.length-1-i into $t4

sll $t5, $t3, 2
add $t6, $a0, $t5
lw $s1, 0($t6)

sll $s3, $t4, 2
add $t7, $a0, $s3
lw $s2, 0($t7)

bne $s1, $s2, return0

# Increase i and start loop again
addi $t3, $t3, 1
j palLoop

return0:
li $v0, 0
jr $ra  

exitLoop:
li $v0, 1
jr $ra
```

Here's the main:

```
.data
charArray: .word 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'w', 'a'

.text
main:

 # Palindrom Function
 la $a0, charArray
 jal palindrome
 move $a0, $v0
 li $v0, 1
 syscall

 # Exit Program
 li $v0, 10
 syscall
```

Thank you in advance for any help. (To specify, palLoop is where I'm having trouble).

Comment: You never said any about _in what way_ the code isn't working. However, having `sub $t4, $t4, $t3 # Puts a.length-1-i into $t4` inside the loop looks suspicious, since subtractions done during earlier iterations will be remembered for later iterations. There are various ways in which that could be fixed, e.g. by simply using a different register for the result, like `$t8`.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly part of your question, but charArray: .word 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'w', 'a' is really a word array containing a chatarter value, not a character array.

It looks like that will wok as you are using word array everywhere, however wont wok if you use a proper character array.

add $t3, $t3, $zero is t3 = t3 + 0 - what is t3 prior to that?

add $t4, $t4, $t1 - same comment

sub $t4, $t4, $t3 # Puts a.length-1-i into $t4  - will overwrite a.length-1 (t4) so is going not be right on the 2nd time through the loop.

Comment: For $t3, I just initialized it to zero and looking back, I don't necessarily know why. $t1 is the length of the array, and $t4 is going to be the index for the second character I'm checking. (charArray.length - 1 - i). Thanks for point out the loop error, definitely new to this and didn't catch that.